# How to push custom array object in ng2 smart table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table
In settings object,we define structure to show fields  like name, title etc.I want to assign object to columns directly.
Object contains fields

```
only.settings = {
  editable: false,
  mode: 'inline',
  add: {
    confirmCreate: true
  },
  edit: {
    confirmSave: true,
  },
  actions: {
    delete: false
  },
  columns: {
    food: {
      title: 'Food',
      filter: false,
    },
    quantity: {
      title: 'Quantity',
      filter: false,
    },
    unit: {
      title: 'Unit',
      filter: false,
      editor: {
        type: 'list',
        config: {
          list: [
            { value: 'gm', title: 'gm' },
            { value: 'slice', title: 'slice' },
            { value: 'cup', title: 'cup' },
            { value: 'glass', title: 'glass' },
            { value: 'pcs', title: 'pcs' },
            { value: 'ml', title: 'ml' },
            { value: 'bowl', title: 'bowl' },
            { value: 'tbspn', title: 'tbspn' }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

I have to create

```
array =>units[]= { value: 'bowl', title: 'bowl' },{ value: 'tbspn', title: 'tbspn' }
```

Want to Assign =>
    list: this.units

but its not working.
It's in case when I get array by web service call.

Answer (score 2):

1. Build an array of { value: unit, title: unit } objects
2. Reassign the settings object **as a new object**

Code:

```
const options = [];
for (const unit of units) {
    options.push({ value: unit.val, title: unit.name });
}
this.settings.columns.unit.editor.config.list = options;
this.settings = Object.assign({}, this.settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you receive your array from the webservice, map the elements to convert to the structure used in smart-table.

For map reference: [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)

It would be something like:

```
config.list = unitsFromWebservice.map(function(unit) {
   return { value: unit, title: unit };
});
```